# fetch details of different students on the basis of Rank in a single query

Tags: mysql

I have a Student table like

```
STUDENT_NAME    MOBILE                  RANK
 RANJAN        1234567890                 2
 ABC           1234589077                 3
 XYZ           1234568888                 1
 PQR           1234567999                 4
```

I want to fetch details of Maximum rank holder & Minimum rank holder student in a single query. How this possible ??

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`.

Comment: min and max and then union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM Student WHERE RANK=(SELECT MAX(RANK) FROM Student ) OR RANK=(SELECT MIN(RANK) FROM Student )